# How to declare a function with more than one statement in Mathjs?

Tags: mathjs

I'm trying to collect several columns of mathjs statements and execute them each against an incrementing counter `x` (1, 2, 3...). After each column has been executed by mathjs, extract the value of `y`.

For example:

```
System input:
x=0    x=1    x=2    x=3
------------------------
User input:
a=1    a=4    a=x        
y=a    y=a-4  y=a-1  y=x
------------------------
Output: 
1      0      1      3
```

There is an additional complication to my problem: each column is 1 second, and we desire to create the waveform of an audio file. That means, between each column, interpolate the values of `x` 44099 times (for sample rate 44100).

It's easy enough to create a range for x, `x*44100:1:(x+1)*44100`. But the tricky part is how to evaluate each of the intervening columns to efficiently extract `y`. You can see how this might be necessary for a sine wave which fluctuates many times a second, with something like `y=sin(x)`. We don't just want the audio file to have a point at `x=0` seconds and another point at `x=1` seconds with nothing in between.

To do this efficiently, my first idea was to declare the entire column as an `f(x)`, eval it with mathjs, and extract `y`. But it seems like mathjs functions can only consist of a single statement.

For example, this fails:

```
f(x) = d = 1; d
f(3) // expect 1; actual: error
```

I understand this is the classic "XY problem" (ha!), but I will certainly accept an answer that solves my X problem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current syntax to do that. A workaround is that elements of an array can include expressions with assignments.

```
f( ) = [d = 1, d][end] # evaluate all expressions in the array and return only the value of the last expression.
f( )                   # 1
```

You have to be very careful with your naming convention as the expressions will assign values in the scope (there are not function scopes)